# Trying to make pitch black night - some meshes still dimly lit

Tags: unity

I have a directional light as a "sun". At night, I need a pitch black scene, but a mesh I'm using as terrain somehow stays faintly lit when the light intensity is 0.

At night:

- The direction light "sun" is rotated so it's beneath my world.
- The sun light is set to black, intensity to 0
- I tried setting fog and ambient light color in RenderSettings to black
- I tried setting ambient intensity to 0

Notice how the background is lighter than the character. Something is causing that light to remain.

**However**, if I enter playmode with the light object inactive, the coloring works fine.

[image]

Comment: Ambient not work?! can you send image from your terrain.please edit your question something like "how can I make pitch black scene?"

Comment: I'm not convinced this is an ambient light problem, because I get pitch black when my scene *starts* without the light object enabled. I've forced ambient light to 0 intensity, black color, and some meshes remain dimly lit. It's not just my terrain mesh now, it's also a low-poly tree mesh I've used from a free low-poly asset on the store.

Comment: After some more debugging it appears to be the "reflectionIntensity" that has to be set to 0. Not sure what's reflecting, but it fixes my issue.

Comment: what shader do you use? try by using Diffuse (or unlit) shader then set environment lighting multiplier and reflection multiplier to 0

Comment: @BotskoNet if you’ve found a solution, you can answer your own question, in case future people with the problem wind up here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging it appears to be the "reflectionIntensity" that has to be set to 0. Not sure what's reflecting, but it fixes my issue.